# Callback to parent function from child not working in IE?

Tags: javascript

I have the functions below and they work fine in firefox and chrome but dont seem to work in IE.

Is this because IE opens in new windows and not tabs like the others?

Parent JS

```
    var wnd = null;
    function openPdf() {
        wnd = window.open('www.example.com');
    }

    function closeWnd() {
        if (wnd != null) {
            wnd.close();
        }   
    alert('Closed');
    }
```

Child JS

```
    function parent_callback() {
        setTimeout("window.opener.closeWnd()",2000);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: do you get an error? if so show us

Comment: so what is the problem really... be specific

Comment: How/when is `parent_callback` is called?

Comment: @RoToRa - The parent_callback() is called onLoad on a iframe.
@Ibu - The problem is that it doesn't work in IE but does in firefox and chrome and want to know why!

Comment: It could be security/anti-irritation feature, to avoid websites flashing open windows for a few seconds. If a website would open a window for just 2 seconds, then **I** would be pissed off and never go there again.

Answer (score 0):

wont fix the whole problem but will improve at least

```
function parent_callback() {
        setTimeout(function (){
          window.opener.close();
         },2000);
    }
```

show your error for a better solution